STM32 UART RX Buffer Not Receiving Data Properly with RTC Time
I am currently experimenting with the RTC TIMER feature.
The purpose of my code is to update the current RTC TIMER time using data received via UART RX.
The problem I’m facing is as follows: When I send the string “SetTime141414” from my PC to the STM32, upon debugging, I can only receive the letter ‘e’ in response.
Although I don’t see any obvious issues with my UART RX code, this behavior is puzzling.
Could this be related to the RTC TIMER?
Alternatively,could you please point out any potential issues in my code?
Thank you for reading, and have a great day!
RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime;
RTC_DateTypeDef sDate;

char temp[100];
uint8_t rx;
uint8_t bufindex=0;
uint8_t buf[30];
uint8_t dataReceived  = 0;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  if(huart->Instance == USART2)
  {
    buf[bufindex] = rx;

    if(rx == '\n')
    {
      dataReceived  = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      bufindex++;
    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rx, 1);
  }
}

err_r handle_data(void)
{
  char *pData;
  uint32_t  lenStr  = 0;

  if((pData = strstr((char *)buf,"SetTime")) != NULL)
  {
    lenStr  = strlen("SetTime");

    sTime.Hours   = ((*(pData + lenStr    ) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 1) - '0');
    sTime.Minutes = ((*(pData + lenStr + 2) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 3) - '0');
    sTime.Seconds = ((*(pData + lenStr + 4) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 5) - '0');

    HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);

    bufindex  = 0;
  }
  else if((pData = strstr((char *)buf,"SetDate")) != NULL)
  {
    lenStr  = strlen("SetDate");

    sDate.Year    = ((*(pData + lenStr    ) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 1) - '0');
    sDate.Month   = ((*(pData + lenStr + 2) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 3) - '0');
    sDate.Date    = ((*(pData + lenStr + 4) - '0') << 4) + (*(pData + lenStr + 5) - '0');

    HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);

    bufindex  = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    bufindex      = 0;
    dataReceived  = 0;
    return  ERROR_NOTFOUND;
  }

  dataReceived  = 0;

  return  ERROR_NONE;
}

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rx, 1);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);

    if(dataReceived == 1)
    {
      if(handle_data() != ERROR_NONE)
      {
        //  HANDLE ERROR BY ERROR NAME
      }
    }

    sprintf(temp,"\r\n20%02x-%02x %02x %02x:%02x:%02x", sDate.Year, sDate.Month, sDate.Date, sTime.Hours, sTime.Minutes,sTime.Seconds); // sprintf to temp

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)temp, strlen(temp), 10);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}



What do you mean "letter e in response"? What is response? Notes: null-terminate buf on newline. Shared variables should be marked volatile (at least dataReceived). Nitpicks: rx is not needed, you could receive directly into buf. In handle_data: bufindex and dataReceived could be just reset at the start instead of all over the function.

I apologize for confusing you. The meaning of "letter e in response" was that when the string "SetTime141414" is transmitted from a PC to the STM32, only the "Se" substring is stored in buf[30]. Additionally, following the advice, I'll directly store data in buf even without an RX signal, and increment the index within the interrupt. In conclusion, the issue has been resolved. The problem was that setting breakpoints in the callback function from the beginning during debugging mode caused the issue. Doing so resulted in receiving only two characters from the string.
